# Eliminar dato de array mediante input php

Tags: php

¿Como sería la eliminación de un dato en un array mediante input? Todo esto con la variable session para tener que hacer un array oculto para que al refrescar no me lo borre. Entiendo que sería algo así, aun que esta mal ya que no funciona

```
 if(isset($_POST['eliminar'])){
    $verboESP = $_POST['verboESP'];


        unset($verbosOculto[$_POST['verboESP']]);
        $verbosOculto = array_values($verbosOculto);



        header('Location: diccionario.php'); 
    }
```

con el input

```
<input type="text" name="verboESP">

        <input type="submit" name="eliminar">
```

Comment: Parece una lógica extraña la que expones en la pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer de forma global, para sugerirte una mejor solución? Si lo que quieres es borrar el dato del POST, tienes que hacerlo así: `unset($_POST['verboESP']);` Ten en cuenta que `$_POST` es en definitiva un array.

Comment: Si respondo a esta pregunta ¿también la borrarás? Por desgracia falta el código que compartiste en ella para dar solución a esta pregunta. Sigues trabajando con `$verbosOculto` en vez de con `$_SESSION['verbosOculto']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por desgracia falta el código que compartiste en la pregunta anterior (borraste la pregunta) para dar solución a esta pregunta.

Sigues insistiendo en trabajar con una variable local, `$verbosOculto`, en vez de trabajar con `$_SESSION['verbosOculto']`.

Deberías hacer:

```
/* Imagino que habrás iniciado previamente el uso de variables de sesión */
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['eliminar'])){
  /* Esto no es necesario, deja la mala costumbre de usar variables intermedias */
  $verboESP = $_POST['verboESP'];
  unset($_SESSION['verbosOculto'][$_POST['verboESP']]);
  /* Eso que haces no sirve para nada porque se perderá al finalizar el script */
  $verbosOculto = array_values($verbosOculto);
  header('Location: diccionario.php'); 
  /* Debes finalizar la ejecución del script actual */
  exit();
}
```